# html form submits arrays in one cell

Tags: html, arrays, forms, express, mongoose

In my html forms, I want to add arrays in different cells, but it pushes all in one cell.

Here's my html input :

```
<input class="recinputs" type="text" name="ingredients[ingredient]" value="egg">
<input class="recinputs" type="text" name="ingredients[amount]" value="2">
<input class="recinputs" type="text" name="ingredients[ingredient]" value="salt">
<input class="recinputs" type="text" name="ingredients[amount]" value="200 gr">
```

Here's my mongoose Schema :

```
  ingredients: [{
    ingredient: {
      type: String,
      ref: 'Ingredient'
    },
    amount: {
      type: String,
    }
  }]
```

and body looks likes this :

```
   { ingredient: [ 'egg', 'salt' ],
     amount: [ '2', '200 gr' ] },
```

and it saves the data in one cell.
But I want it to add each one in different cells.
How should I change my inputs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I acutually don't know what is what so the naming convention may be a little confusing.. but it gives what you desire try it using this code

```
let objArray = [];
let foodItem = {ingredient: null, amount : null}

for(let i = 0; i< obj.ingredient.length ;i++){
    foodItem.ingredient = obj.ingredient[i];
    foodItem.amount = obj.amount[i];
    objArray.push(foodItem);
    foodItem = {ingredient: null, amount : null};
}
```

so using you model you should do it like this

```
let item = new Model(objArray );
```

objArray is created like this

```
0: {ingredient: "egg", amount: "2"}
1: {ingredient: "salt", amount: "200 gr"}
```

Then finally save it using 
    item.save();